# Is using single quotes for string literals faster than double quotes?

Tags: bash

This is not a question about micro optimization. I'm just interested if using single quotes for string literals is faster than using double quotes (because no variable expansion will happen).

Example:

```
echo 'This is a string' # should a faster
echo "This is a string"
```

I've tried to measure this (using a large loop and time) but couldn't come up with a real conclusion.

Any ideas on this?

**EDIT**

I'm also interested why the performance difference is so small... one would think that variable expansion requires some sort of parsing the string, which should make a notable difference.

Comment: Don't think so... even it has I believe you can ignore it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was curious about this too, so I ran a few measurement on an Intel i7-8700 Hackintosh.
Here are the results:

### Single quotes

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do
        echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
done

sh test.sh  7,40s user 0,80s system 97% cpu 8,403 total
```

### Double quotes

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do
        echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
done

sh test.sh  9,96s user 0,87s system 97% cpu 11,050 total
```

### No quotes (effectively same as double quotes)

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do
        echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
done

sh test.sh  9,97s user 0,88s system 98% cpu 11,068 total
```

### Singles quotes with variable concatenation

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do
        echo 'abc'$i'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
done

sh test.sh  9,53s user 0,91s system 97% cpu 10,707 total
```

### Double quotes with variable concatenation

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do
        echo "abc${i}defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
done

sh test.sh  11,78s user 0,94s system 97% cpu 13,028 total
```

So yeah using single or double quotes have an impact on performances. As said before, this is because of the parsing that bash does when trying to expand variables in strings.

As to why the difference is “so small”, I’m not entirely sure, but bash is itself an interpreter, so a lot of operations still occurs when using single quotes, and I guess the test to search a “$” character in the string doesn’t have much impact on performances next to all those other operations.

Comment: Results may vary. I see little or no difference between the single-quoted and unquoted cases.

Comment: @chepner Maybe the shell you use have a lesser impact than mine? I’m running `time sh test.sh` in a zsh shell.

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes (because it won't look for expansions of `$var` etc).

In reality, doubt that you'll ever see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be (just a little bit)faster. Do a little experiment - echo a string with 10 000 $ signs. In the first case (double quotes) you will have to escape them, while in the second you don't need to. The first string is twice longer and thus processing it will be slower. This is an extreme example and I doubt you will observe difference anywhere in real life.

EDIT: in response to your edit. I believe the parsing in the double qoute case happens using determined automata and thus again is linear. This is just speculation. Still you can imagine how variable parsing happens - if one sees non-escaped $ sign, then you have a variable to follow.